# Change the type of an html-element with jQuery

Tags: types, htmlelements

I want to change an h4-element to an h3-element.

Is there any easy possibility with jQuery?

Of course there is the .replaceWith-function. But the content of my h3-elemtent must not be deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
$("h4").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.replaceWith("<h3>"+self.html() + "</h3>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine for me. But I had to change it a little bit, because there were only three h4-titles which I wanted to change.